# How to access other servers using NodeJS?

Tags: php, xml, node.js

I have a node.js local server containing a html file and a Apache server containing php file which gets news feed from google as xml string and send it to html page(node server) to display it. But it does not showing any results.
If i place both files on the same server then it works fine. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, your code is working perfectly when both running on same server. Problem comes if your PHP code and node are on different server. Basically the problem is on HTTP request.

You can try by adding a single line inside your node.js controller.

> var http = require('http');

```
> var options = {
>       host: domainurl,
>       path: request.path, // example Phpapi
>       method: 'GET'
>     };

> 
>     var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
>       console.log(res); // data you get from php server
>     });
> 
>     req.on('error', function(e) {
>       console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
>     });
>     
>     req.end();
```

Comment: Have you checked request url?

Comment: I have to get response from php server to node.js.
when i use it in php file, html didn't show any result

Comment: You can simply do Http request from node.js server/code to your php API's. If this approach suites you well i can help you with code..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Use the following code in php file at start before any code.
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000").
3000 is port on which node.js server is running.                                                   And also use following code in html file (placed on node server) which will receive data.
localhost:80 is port on which getrss.php file is running.

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:80/getrss.php?q="+str,true);

xmlhttp.send();